# Collatz Conjecture - analyzing ending possibilities and the need to prove loops

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, proof-explanation, collatz-conjecture

According to the rules of the Collatz Conjecture if $n$ is odd then execute $3n + 1$ and  when $n$ is even execute $n/2$.  Repeat until (supposedly) reaching $n = 1$.

examples:

$1 → 4 → 2 → 1$

$13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1$

In this experiment I have taken a set of the first $2500$ consecutive odd numbers and named an element in that set $x$. I have then checked what are the common endings, and these are the first few results:

When $x ≥ 1$ will always end in  $4 →  2 →  1$ (2500/2500 times)

When $x ≥ 3$ will always end in  $16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1$ (2499/2500 times)

When $x ≥ 5$ will end in $40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1$ (2351/2500 times)

OR

When $x ≥ 5$ will end in $64 → 32 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1$  (146/2500 times)

When $x ≥ 7$ will end in $160 → 80 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1$ (1200/2500 times)

OR

When $z ≥ 7$ will end in  $52 → 26 → 13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 →4 → 2 → 1$ (1150/2500 times)

OR

When $x ≥ 7$ will end in $256 → 128 → 64 → 32 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1$  (145/2500 times)

...

*Note the $3$ ending possibilities of $x ≥ 7$ are extensions of the $2$ the ending possibilities of $x ≥ 5$, and the $2$ ending possibilities of $x ≥ 5$ are extensions of the $1$ ending possibility of $x ≥ 3$, and the $1$ ending possibility of $x ≥ 3$ is an extension of the $1$  ending possibility of $x ≥ 1$.

The heuristic shows that  for $x ≥ y$, where $y$ is any natural odd number, $x$ will have a limited amount of ending possibilities, that are extensions of the ending possibilities when $x ≥ y-2$.

My set is a finite set of only the first $2500$ odd numbers, I am definitely not claiming proof or even a direction for a proof (way above my level). I am trying to learn what needs to be proved, besides the obvious that we need to prove that the end result should always be $1$.

The heuristic shows $x ≥ y$,  $x$ can only end in a limited amount of ending possibilities depending on $y$ and these endings possibilities are extensions of the the ending possibilities when $x ≥ y-2$, would it be sufficient to prove the conjecture is true?

In other words,  If I start with $1$ and mapping backwards all the possibilities permitted by the Collatz rules, will I eventually hit all the numbers?

Every Time I will hit a new number. It means that this number has no loops, since we got to this number from $1$,(that number would not have been able to appear earlier without ending in $1$.)

So if we present the conjecture in such way, we don't have to prove possible loops?

Comment: Not quite sure of the question. A proof that any starting point eventually iterates into some fixed interval (or other set) where all numbers in the interval are (somehow) already known to get to $1$ would be a proof of the conjecture. One can identify many sets, including large or infinite sets, whose members are known to get to $1$. The hard part is finding one where one can also prove everything else will wind up there. Roughly speaking, "does everything eventually get into [some big set I where I know everything eventually gets to $1$]" seems no easier than "does everything get to $1$."

Comment: @leslie townes But what about a proof that shows that all numbers have a finite way to get to $1$ ?

Comment: The proof requires - there are two challenges: 1. Show that there is always a "limit circle" - a closed list of numbers - no divergence. 2. Show that there is only one such cycle containing the vale 1.

Comment: @Moti but if i can prove that a number has only a finite amount of possible endings, then i can prove that the Collatz Conjecture is true because these endings always lead to the vale 1.

Comment: If you can prove convergence than you still need to prove that there is only ONE cycle. Try to define under what conditions a cycle exist  and than that there is only one solution.

Comment: It would be sufficient to prove that , no matter which is the starting value (except $1$), the sequence will eventually get below this start value. But this is apparently utterly out of reach. If this conjecture would be proven within the next, lets say , $50$ years, this would be already sensational. We cannot even be sure that there is a proof or disproof.

Comment: @Peter so there will be no way to prove that a starting value Must have one of the limited possible endings that lead to 1, without demonstrating it all the way from the beginning ?

Comment: The conjecture is open since a long time (since $1937$) and because it seems to be so easy surely many mathematicians tried to prove it. The "obious" ideas were surely analyzed to an incredible deepness. So we can safely assume that they are doomed to fail. There are in principle three possibilities : (to be continued)

Comment: (continuation) $(1)$ There is a nontrivial cycle (contating not $1$). In this case the collatz conjecture can , in principle , be disproven. $(2)$ There are no nontrivial cycles, but there is a diverging series. It will be hard to prove a sequence to be diverging, so in this case we might be doomed. $(3)$ the conjecture is true (to be continued)

Comment: (continuation) In this case, there can or cannot be a proof. Even, if there is a proof , it can be incredibly difficult to find it. In short, there is no "easy" way to solve this conjecture. To be honest, when I heard from this problem the first time , I was still in school , tried to prove it (because I was convinced that this has been solved), of course failed and much later heard that it is a famous unsolved problem.

Comment: Apologize for the typos, but after $5$ minutes edition is no more possible.

Comment: @Peter I understand and by no means I claim to even have the bits of knowledge to even try and solve the conjecture. I will leave that tasks to the pros, but i was just wondering about the different approaches that are taken in order to even begin solving the problem. I knew one of the aspects of the conjecture are the possible loops, but the fact that in a finite set, it can be proven that a number has only a limit of ways in which it could end and these ways always lead to 1, made me think that if that can be proved for an infinite set, there is no need to prove loops.

Comment: @Peter But I now understand that such a generalization is impossible. It is impossible to prove that a number must end in limited possible ways without knowing it's beginning.(For now and probably the next 50 years)

Answer (score 1):

While the ending possibilities may be finite, only if the beginnings don't diverge or loop will the ending possibilities matter.

We can look and see, all even numbers fall to their odd parts. Odd numbers of form $4k+1$ go through $4k+1\to 12k+4\to 6k+2\to 3k+1$ which shows they can't be the lowest member, of a lowest escaping or looping sequence. However numbers of form $4k+3$ go through: $$4k+3\to 12k+10\to 6k+5\to 18k+16\to 9k+8$$ Now we have a problem , if $k$ is even we can divide by 2 to get $9j+4$ (for which we have a similar conundrum) otherwise, we go to $27k+25$ which will be down to $27m+26$ (for which the conundrum shows up again)

so in most of these cases we need to mod by a higher power of $2$ to get anywhere. parity falls to the last term any time the modulus is even, hence the self similarity of the Collatz graph.